# Activity not started when going through "Getting Started" with Android

Tags: android

I'm learning Android development using Android's training there: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

At the end of the first part (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) when I click the button, nothing happens, I don't even get an error in the log, just the following lines:

```
11-25 13:26:30.240      422-422/com.android.systemui V/PanelView﹕ animationTick called with dtms=0; nothing to do (h=0.6308222 v=0.0)
11-25 13:26:30.620      370-552/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b1ebc6b0 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b2016910
```

My project code is here: http://d.pr/f/ED5O

Comment: You are using Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: I'd suggest you use Eclipse. The tutorials are all for Eclipse, Android Studio is still only a developer preview. I'm assuming you are an Android beginner, my feeling is you will run into more problems like this.

Comment: You're right, I just restarted the training with Eclipse and now it works. Eclipse is BS and I can't wait for Google to definitively switch to Intellij but in the meantime I'll cope with Eclipse. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I must be the only person that actually likes Eclipse on here :) Tried Android Studio and hated it, it's not complete yet. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it here, but I think that you have to move the `sendMessage` function to the fragment as the button command is specified in the fragment layout xml file.

Actually for a first project, I think that it is probably best that you do not jump to the usage of fragments yet and have the button in the activity layout.

Comment: The problem is that the documentation is out of sync with Android Studio. And the project Android Studio generated has this fragment structure. And since I don't know how these things work yet, it's kind of hard to come back to the way it should be.

Comment: Did you try moving the `sendMessage` method to the `PlaceholderFragment` class? That may be enough to solve the problem. Btw, you will need also to replace the `startActivity(intent);`  by `getActivity().startActivity(intent)`

Comment: No, I ended up switching back to Eclipse in order to avoid that kind of surprises along the way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, using Android Studio to follow along the Android training is still a bad idea. The project generated by Android studio has fragments in it that break the example code. Let's hope Google fixes that soon and we can definitely get rid of this Eclipse BS.